# how to copy the div to some div and remove original div

Tags: jquery, dom

Suppose I have the following markup

```
<div id="test">
  <div class="original">hi</div>
  <div class="news"></div>
  <div class="duplicate"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to remove `original` and paste it to `duplicate`

The result should look like this

```
<div id="test">   
  <div class="news"></div>
  <div class="duplicate"><div class="original">hi</div></div>
</div>
```

I tried like this

```
var orig = $('.original');
orig.remove().clone(true).appendTo('.duplicate'); // but not working
```

Comment: No need to clone it then, just move it

Comment: not working also without clone

Comment: What means "not working", because it works

Comment: you need the whole original div or the data in original div?

Comment: BTW, i hope you know IDs must be unique on context page

Comment: I knew it why mine was not working, so I think I should ask new question for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this way:

```
$(".original").detach().appendTo(".duplicate");
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Js6qY/)

Or simply

```
$(".original").appendTo("duplicate");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var original = $('.original');
var duplicate = $('.duplicate');
duplicate.append(original);
```

From [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

*If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):*

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CgfPf/)

Answer (score 2):

`appendTo()` will 'move' the element:

```
var $orig = $('.original');
$orig.appendTo('.duplicate');
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7mb/)